# Plotting a matrix cartesian coordinate using polar coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-2.x

I know a matrix f[r,phi] in polar coordinate. I want to plot it in cartesian coordinate. Following is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import math

f = np.zeros((1024,90))  #In polar co-ordinate 

D = 0.28                #Source to isocenter distance
h = np.zeros(1024)
h[0:512] = np.linspace(0,1,512)
h[513:] = np.linspace(1,0,511) 

for r in range(0,1024) :
    for phi in range(0,90) :
        for b in range(0,360) :
            for s in range(0,1024) :
                U = (D + r*sin(b-phi))/D
                l = math.pow(U,-2)
                k = D/(math.pow((math.pow(D,2)+math.pow(s,2)),0.5))   
                f[r,phi] = 0.5*l*k*q[s,b]*h[s]

I =np.zeros((725,725))

for x in range(1,726) :
    for y in range(1,726) :
        r = math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2)
        phi = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x))
        I[x,y] = f[r,phi]
```

Here the polar coordinate r varies from (0,1024) and phi from (0,90). But I have applied a filer 'h' which is a ramp filter. So the final f does not exactly have 1024*90 elements. I want to plot the image f in cartesian coordinate and I have set the dimension as (725,725) which is flexible. But I am getting the following  error.

```
I[x,y] = f[r,phi]
IndexError: index (1025) out of range (0<=index<1024) in dimension 0
```

Could anyone please suggest me a way to plot the function f in cartesian coordinate?

Comment: Is there a special reason this question has been tagged [tag:r]?

Comment: No special reasons. Just a mistake.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/ this will surely you

Comment: Three issues with your code: (1) you index `I` from `1` to `725`, but it should be indexed from `0` to `724`. (2) `r = math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2)` this produces **very** large values for `r`, which is why you get the error. (3) `sin` and `q` are not defined.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed (4) in looping over `b` and `s` you overwrite `f[r,phi]` 360*1024 times and only the last one is used. There is either a lot of optimization potential or a problem in your logic.

Comment: I have imported sin from math and q is a 1024*360 matrix. These are part of the code which I haven'e mentioned above. I have changed r to square to sqrt of the what it was previously. So I guess now it's okay. And my code initially had I from 0 to 724. But I am using atan(y/x) which was giving me an error of dividing with zero. Hence I changed it to 1 to 725. Is it not right?